# Putting a custom directory inside wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a simple HTML microsite, which I want to put inside my wordpress website. For example: Wordpress website is: abc.com

I want to put my microsite inside this wordpress site. So URL becomes:

abc.com/microsite/

But, wordpress treats any url as its own. How can put "abc.com/microsite/" urls to Wordpress Ignore list. So that any pages inside microsite folder executes independently.

Comment: For your own sanity in the long run (to avoid problems with clashing URLs, for example), I'd recommend using a subdomain instead, so the two sites are technically separate; i.e. http://microsite.example.com/  but it's still clear from the URL it's part of your website.

Comment: thanks! @williamt I'll remember this for future. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put you folder 'microsite' in root`(Where you find wp-admin,wp-content and wp-include folder)`. 
and 
you are able to access the folder 
"abc.com/microsite/ by this url

Comment: It worked on Localhost! But still not working on certain server! Don't know what is the issue. Thanks for Helping!

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having issues with accessing the subfolder, try renaming the .htaccess to .htaccess-bak in order for WordPress to regenerate the file again. **Understand that your website might temporarily go down.**

I've found this solution to help in some cases, but I don't know exactly why, ergo I am not sure it will work. And if you feel uncomfortable editing the .htaccess file I suggest you learn more about it (as should I). It is a very powerful file and WordPress uses it a good deal.

P.S. The file is located in the same folder, WordPress' root folder where you find /wp-admin/, /wp-content/, etc. It is hidden by some hosting providers, but I've always been able to find them through FTP with the hosting companies I've used before.